# How to replace the number values of a column by low to high in python?

Tags: python, sorting, replace

i have this:

```
A 29
B 45
C 75
D 22
E 58
E 58
F 61
G 47
G 47
```

and i need to get this:

```
A 2 
B 3
C 7
D 1
E 5
E 5
F 6
G 4
G 4
```

i think about sort ascending and rank and after change the column values but this is not applied to the duplicates in the first column. Need the equal values in column 1 has the same rank value in the column 2. Anyone?

Comment: Do you have this as a string?

Comment: Is this pure python? pandas? CSV?

Comment: You say "I have this". How do you have it? In a file perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the values, enumerate that, then loop through the original data getting the indexes of the value of the original data. Below is an example of what I mean: <sub>*(just implement it to your needs)*</sub>

```
data = {
    "A": 29,
    "B": 45,
    "C": 75,
    "D": 22,
    "E": 58,
    "E": 58,
    "F": 61,
    "G": 47,
}

sorted_data = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(sorted(data.values()), 1)))

result = {k: sorted_data[v] for k, v in data.items()}
```

result

```
{'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 7, 'D': 1, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 4}
```